# Table with Data from Two POJO Bean Data Controls

Tags: jdeveloper, oracle-adf

JDev 11.1.1.5.0

Use case:
Display a table where the first row will contain values from one POJO Bean data control and the second row will contain values from another.
I have managed to display the first row from one bean data control, now I want to show the second row with the other.

Hope the use case is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a pojo that returns a collection that combines the data from the two pojos into a single record/object.
Then create a table where you put two fields in each column and show the details of the record that way.